# Invalid Middleware found in Next.JS-13 (App Based Routing)

Tags: typescript, mongodb, next.js13

I am designing a basic user authentication system with Login , Signup and Logout functionalities . I have created the middleware.ts file in src directory which is a sibling to the app directory.
Here is my middleware.ts file
with `(path : src/middleware.ts)`

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import type { NextRequest } from "next/server";

export function middleware(request : NextRequest)
{
    const path = request.nextUrl.pathname;

    const isPublicPath = path.includes('/login') || path.includes('/signup');

    const token = request.cookies.get('token')?.value || '';

    if(isPublicPath && token)
    {
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/' , request.nextUrl));
    }

    if(!isPublicPath && !token)
    {
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/login' , request.nextUrl));
    }


}

export const config = {
    matcher:[
        '/',
        '/profile',
        '/login',
        'signup',
    ],
}
```

Whenever I start my server , I get follwoing errors

> source does not start with / for route {"source":"signup"}

and  afterwards I get this error :

> Invalid middleware found.

I tried to restart the server after saving all changes but it would be the same . The same kind of issue arose previously where the server refused to connect but it did after a few changes.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in the matcher array in config.

it is 'signup'
it should be '/signup'